# Invalid left-hand in assignment?

Tags: javascript, debugging

This is the whole function:

```
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        delete game.keys[e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which] = true;
    });
```

This is the line that is throwing the error:

```
    delete game.keys[e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which] = true;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 1):

When using `delete` you need to give some variable afterwards: `delete someVar`. It's not valid to do an assignment in the `delete` using `=`. So remove `= true`:

```
delete game.keys[e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which];
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for equals true:

```
delete game.keys[e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which];
```